# How to dual boot Mac OS X and Ubuntu without rEFIt

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, mac, refit

I want to install Ubuntu on my Mac but I don't want have to use rEFIt. Can I do that? Can I just hold the option key on startup and use that to pick what I startup with? And if so would I install Ubuntu the same way just skipping the rEFIt part? Thanks. And I'm running OS X 10.8.2

Comment: Rockon, did you installed grub on your main "/" partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too am a OS X/Ubuntu User. Yes you can choose to hold Option (At least on my system) on start up, or you can go the route I took and install rEFInd (A newer version of the abandoned rEFIt), though rEFIt still functions fine (With a few outdated icons) and is easier to install. I'd recommend rEFIt or rEFInd personally, but if you really want to you can choose to just hold Option down on start up :)

- Ubuntu 12.10 and OS X 10.8.2 W/ rEFInd on a Early 2011 MBP (My Setup)

Comment: I'm also a OSX/Ubuntu user. I also installed rEFIt, i'm using OSX 10.6 and Ubuntu Gnome Remix.

Comment: If rockon999s answer is the solution to your question then please accept it!!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question was "How can I do X?", while this answer is basically "Yes, you can do X".